# Cant find the problem, IE appearance problem

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, appearance

I have this ajax_update script that updates file.php every 60 seconds.. Now file.php outputs this after updated a table:

```
<div id="message" style="display: none;" onclick="closeNotice()">this works
</div>
```

What I am trying to do is that after file.php have updated a field in the database(points), there will come up a message like stackoverflow at the top(just like when you earn a badge) saying that you have received 1 point. anyway:

Here's my update script:

```
function addpoints()  { 
  var postFile = 'addpoints.php?userid='+ $('#user_id_points').val();
  $.post(postFile, function(data){
    $("#points").html(data).find("#message").fadeIn("slow")
    setTimeout(addpoints, 5000);
  });
}
```

Now, i have  in my index.php, and a load function addpoints script..

But why will this only appear in FF and not in IE?

I have checked with w3c validator, if it could be unclosed tags or something, i fixed all problems and now i have no errors, but still it doesnt work.

So what to do?

You can see my site here: http://azzyh.dk/newgen/area/member/indextest.php

(use FF and you will see the message at the top, use IE and you wont see anything)

Im pretty lost. thank you

Comment: i'd break up your jquery chain and try each part separately in IE to debug and find out if .html(), .find() or .fadein() is the problem.

Comment: How do i do this, thank you for your comment

Answer (score 2):

Display issues in IE can be a really pain i cant help you directly, But firebug lite which can be plugged into any broswer should help you see whats going on in IE

[Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite)

If you add the following as a bookmark and stick it on your tool bar it will enable firebug lite off any webpage with a single click.

```
javascript:var%20firebug=document.createElement('script');firebug.setAttribute('src','http://getfirebug.com/releases/lite/1.2/firebug-lite-compressed.js');document.body.appendChild(firebug);(function(){if(window.firebug.version){firebug.init();}else{setTimeout(arguments.callee);}})();void(firebug);
```